# function_exists performance cost

Tags: php, performance

Does anyone have any data about the computational cost of `function_exists`?
I have this snippet:

```
if(function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
    fastcgi_finish_request();
}
```

It is needed only because the function doesn't exist in dev environment, but it will always exist in production.
Since I need high efficiency (this script is called millions of times per day and must be as fast as possible), should I remove this check before deploying to production?

Comment: Why does a function not exist in dev-environment? Make it available there and remove the check.

Comment: How about an `if (! function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) { function fastcgi_finish_request(){} }` no-op declaration in some kind of `debug.php` or `startup.php` file?

Comment: If we're talking about calling this function once per request, I would seriously doubt that it, performance wise, will make much of difference. But as @Seb says, make it available in dev as well?

Comment: It's a serious performance issue if you were to do `foreach($funcs as $f) { function_exists($f); }` → but it's not the `_exists` check then. These kind of built-in function calls are most always negligible in comparison to loops and database queries.

Comment: Is there a way to add a custom function outside the code? Like in php.ini? Because if I have to do `if(I'm in dev) { do smth }` it's another useless check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this function if sometimes this function may not exist.

You can remove this check and implement empty method `function fastcgi_finish_request() {}` in dev environment that does nothing.

Comment: Yes I'll add this in a gitignored file like config.php

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question about performance so i did a simple script to test it, code and results below.

```
PHP 5.6.40 (1.000.000)
checkByFunction: 0.16808795928955
checkByVersion: 0.97429490089417
```

---

```
<?php
function checkByVersion($expectedMajor = 5, $expectedMinor = 5)
{
    //Explode (semver.org MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH)
    $phpversion = explode(".", phpversion());
    $phpversion_major = (int) $phpversion[0];
    $phpversion_minor = (int) $phpversion[1];

    //if php_version > 5 or 5.5
    if($phpversion_major > $expectedMajor || ($phpversion_major == $expectedMajor && $phpversion_minor >= $expectedMinor) ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Test
$iterations = 1000000;

$byFunctionTimeStart = 0;
$byFunctionTimeEnd = 0;

$byVersionTimeStart = 0;
$byVersionTimeEnd = 0;

//ByFunction
$byFunctionTimeStart = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i < $iterations; $i++) { 
    function_exists("curl_file_create");
}
$byFunctionTimeEnd = microtime(true);
$byFunctionTimeResult = $byFunctionTimeEnd - $byFunctionTimeStart;

//ByVersion
$byVersionTimeStart = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i < $iterations; $i++) { 
    checkByVersion();
}
$byVersionTimeEnd = microtime(true);
$byVersionTimeResult = $byVersionTimeEnd - $byVersionTimeStart;

echo "<pre>";
echo "PHP ".phpversion()." (".number_format($iterations, 0, ".", ".").")";
echo "<br/>checkByFunction: ".$byFunctionTimeResult;
echo "<br/>checkByVersion: ".$byVersionTimeResult;
echo "</pre>";
```